# Why does CPython allow to execute non existing method

Tags: python

Consider this simple code:

**codeA**:

```
class Test:
    pass

t = Test()
t.__str__()             # 1
t.non_existing_method() # 2
```

**codeB**:

```
class Test(object):
    pass

t = Test()
t.__str__()             # 1
t.non_existing_method() # 2
```

Why in **codeA** doesn't CPython complain about non existing **_*str*_** method (when it complains about #2)? It is neither staticmethod nor classmethod. It is also not inherited from parent object as in **codeB**. This works as I expected in IronPython (it compains about **str** in codeA).

In **codeB** CPython behaves as I expect - does not complain in case #1 as **_*str*_** is now inherited.

**Update:**

codeA output(CPython):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\eclipse_workspace\py_test\src\test_module.py", line 6, in <module>
    t.non_existing_method() # 2
AttributeError: 'Test' object has no attribute 'non_existing_method'
```

Comment: CodeA.#1 [certainly complains for me](http://ideone.com/4yycis). Please copy-paste the precise code you are executing and the output you are seeing.

Comment: This is exact code - doublechecked

Comment: If you are using python3 note that all classes inherrit from object in this version.

Comment: You meant the opposite... In CodeB: It won't complain but in CodeA it will.

Comment: @Artur - in that case, please copy-paste the results you are seeing.

Comment: @jb - post an answer - you were first according to timestamps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 2.x, your case A will complain that `__str__` does not exist. `Test` is an old-style class (i.e., it does not inherit from `object`).

```
>>> print type(t)
<type 'instance'>
```

These behave differently from new-style classes, sometimes in non-intuitive ways. Which is one reason there are now new-style classes.

In Python 3.x, both are new-style classes and therefore inherit from `object`, so neither complains since `object` has a perfectly cromulent `__str__`.

Now with regard to IronPython not complaining in case A, perhaps it handles the method resolution slightly differently from the way CPython does. `instance` does in fact have a `__str__` method, which IronPython might be picking up:

```
>>> print type(t).__str__
<slot wrapper '__str__' of 'object' objects>
```

I am not sure the CPython behavior here with respect to old-style classes is canonical or even documented, so IronPython may not actually be wrong. Remember, IronPython is a *re-implementation* of Python on the .NET framework. It was not developed by the original Python developers. This kind of minor edge-case inconsistency with the mothership is probably inevitable.